# How do I get excel to merge cells only when other cells are filled?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to merge cells using a formula so that the cells only merge when cells on another tab are filled.
I have 2 tabs with the same amount of columns in each. I want cells a1-d1 to merge in tab 1 when cells a1-d1 in tab 2 are filled and for the value of d1 in tab 2 to be inputted into the newly merged cells in tab 1.
this is what I have:

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `tab`? `Sheet`? What have you done so far?

Comment: hey, so when cells a1-a4 are filled in tab 2 i want it to merge cells a1-a4 in tab 1 and put the value of cell a4 in tab 2 into the newly merged cells of tab 1...i hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Excel VBA Methods and Function (Excel Macros) overview

Since you want to change cells i do not believe that you can use a formula (even not a user defined one). Therefore i wrote an excel vba macro for your problem.

- FirstRows(): Is the starting point. It loops over 10 rows and calls the other methods
- CheckEmptyCellValues(curRow): This method checks for empty cells in tab2 (sheet 2 in excel)
- MergeCells(curRow) takes the current row as a number (any integer from 1 to max amount of rows) and merges the cells from column 1 to 4 on Sheet 1 (the first sheet in excel)

### Fully working demo tested with 4 columns and 10 rows

```
Sub FirstRows()
   Sheets(1).Select
   For curRow = 2 To 11
      Merge = CheckEmptyCellValues(curRow)
      If Merge = 4 Then
        MergeCells (curRow)
        cellValue = Sheets(2).Cells(curRow, 4).Value
        Sheets(1).Cells(curRow, 1).Value = cellValue
      End If
   Next
 End Sub
  
Sub MergeCells(curRow)
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range(Cells(curRow, 1), Cells(curRow, 4)).MergeCells = True
End Sub

Function CheckEmptyCellValues(curRow)
    Merge = 0
    Sheets(2).Select
    For i = 1 To 4
        If Len(Cells(curRow, i).Value) > 0 Then
            Merge = Merge + 1
        End If
    Next
    CheckEmptyCellValues = Merge
End Function
```

Below you can see the result. The values from sheet 2 haven been copied to sheet 1 (second image). In Sheet 1 the Cells in a row are merged (in row 2 from Cell A2 up to Cell D2 (A2-D2 is now just one cell) if in the first image (sheet 2) every cell (from column a to column d) in a row had a value.

[image: The data source from tab 2 (sheet 2)]
[image: The merged cells and copied values on sheet 1]

### Bugs in the modified code

There are a few things in the modifiend code that are not possible or could lead to a wrong understanding

```
Function CheckEmptyCellValues(curColumn) 
  Merge = 0 
  Sheets(2).Select 
  For i = A To d 
    If Len(Cells(curColumn, 11).Value) > 0 Then 
        Merge = Merge + 1 
    End If 
  Next 
  CheckEmptyCellValues = Merge 
End Function
```

1. The line `For i = A To d`  is not possible. If you want to use a loop you have to use numbers: `For i = 1 To 4`  this would repeat the code between `For` and `Next`4 times starting with 1
2. This line `Cells(curColumn, 11).Value` is technical correct but misleading. Excel uses the first value after `(`for the row-index and the second value for the column-index. Both values have to be a number: Cells(4,2).Value returns the Cell value from the 4th. row and the second Column (in the Excel Gui the Cell B4)

Try changing this line `For i = A To d` to this `For i = 1 To 4` and see if that returns the wished result.

#### Bugs part 2

In your other modification you have some of the same bugs:

- The loop `For curColumn = A to d` needs numbers instead of letters (unless A and d were a variable filled with a number but according to your code sample this is not the case
- The line `cellValue = Sheets(2).Cells(curColumn, d).Value` has the same bug, if d is just the letter d and not something like `d = 4` than you can not use it in a loop.

This is the code from your comment:

```
 Sub FirstRows() 
  Sheets(1).Select 
    For curColumn = A To d 
       Merge = CheckEmptyCellValues(curColumn) 
       If Merge = d Then 
          MergeCells(curColumn) 
          cellValue = Sheets(2).Cells(curColumn, d).Value 
          Sheets(1).Cells(curColumn, d).Value = cellValue 
       End If
    Next 
  End 
  Sub Sub MergeCells(curColumn) 
     Sheets(1).Select 
     Range(Cells(curColumn, 1), Cells(curColumn, d)).MergeCells = True 
  End Sub
```

Be carefull it is not running.

Comment: ok thanks, i am not too familiar with macros so i will play around with it and let you know if i get stuck

Comment: I can't fine the module folder? Just to be clear the cells in the first tab won't have any data in until they are merged (they will be conditionally formatted though). Thanks so much for your help

Comment: ok so I found it and it nearly works!!! Is there anyway to have it so that where it says complete it instead just has the date on the first merged line? thanks so much this is great

Comment: For adding macros to excel you can take a look here at 2 minutes 45 seconds: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pfdm7xs3QE

Can you clarify your last comment i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: thanks i'll take a look. sorry i'm totally not making any sense here. what i want it to do is merge the rows so it will merge a1-d1. not a1-a4. and then instead of saying complete in the newly merged cells and putting the value of cell d1 in row 2 it will just put this value in the newly merged a1-d1 cell. sorry about that. i'll look at the videos for sure. thank you

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to merge cells in a row. The code works perfectly the only thing it does is it writes 'complete' into the merged cells (a2 to d2) instead of inputting the value from d2 in tab 2. it has put the value of d2 into row 3 (and merged cells a3 to d3). thank you

Comment: If you have modified my code you could post it here and i will take a look. The word 'complete' is not in my source code. So i have no idea how it manages to be written into the target cell on tab 1.
Could it be that the word is written in one of the source cells from tab2?

Comment: oh yes it is sorry, i think it's because i initially mixed up columns and rows. anyway i have modified the code but it is not working properly:

Comment: i am not sure how to post the code, do i have to post it as an image?

Comment: i've edited my initial question so it makes more sense. thank you

Comment: Sub FirstRows()
   Sheets(1).Select
   For curColumn = A To d
      Merge = CheckEmptyCellValues(curColumn)
      If Merge = d Then
        MergeCells (curColumn)
        cellValue = Sheets(2).Cells(curColumn, d).Value
        Sheets(1).Cells(curColumn, d).Value = cellValue
      End If
   Next
 End Sub

Sub MergeCells(curColumn)
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range(Cells(curColumn, 1), Cells(curColumn, d)).MergeCells = True
End Sub

Comment: Function CheckEmptyCellValues(curColumn)
    Merge = 0
    Sheets(2).Select
    For i = A To d
        If Len(Cells(curColumn, 11).Value) > 0 Then
            Merge = Merge + 1
        End If
    Next
    CheckEmptyCellValues = Merge
End Function

Comment: If you want to you can add the code in your own post (your question not the comment). This would make it easier to read it. I tried to add your modified code to your qestion  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/901378 but some of the moderators think that this is my attempt to temper with your question.

Comment: hey, i'm trying but i don't know how, it won't let me post it because it isn't formatted correctly??

Comment: If you add 4 spaces in front or mark the relevant lines and press the code button "{}" it will intend it automatically.